# Slide down to a div when Youtube video Play ends

Tags: jquery, html, youtube

Is there any way to slide down to a div when a yoututbe video play ends in a webpage...?

Comment: How are you embedding the YT video? Iframe? Flash player? HTML5?

Comment: Have a look at the YouTube JavaScript Player API - https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference and the `player.getPlayerState()` function

Comment: I am using tubular js to show the video in the background of a page...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with Youtube Api by subscribing on events which you are interesting in.

For example, in such way:

```
<div id="player"></div>

<script src="http://www.youtube.com/player_api"></script>

<script>

    // create youtube player
    var player;
function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
        height: '390',
        width: '640',
        videoId: '0Bmhjf0rKe8',
        events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
        }
    });
}

// autoplay video
function onPlayerReady(event) {
    event.target.playVideo();
}

// when video ends
function onPlayerStateChange(event) {        
    if(event.data === 0) {            
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $("#elementtoScrollToID").offset().top
        }, 2000);
    }
}

</script>

<div id='elementtoScrollToID' class='my_div'> Hello! </div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/h9rp9/